# Comparison of Random Decision Forest implementation in C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, random-forest

I am currently converting some R code into C++ code, and I need a “good” C++ Random Decision Forest implementation.

So far I found three big implementation (tmva, alglib and openCv), some “small/outdated” ones (like librf), and I need to choose one of them:

Do you guys have some good/bad experiences and/or some recommendations about  those libraries (or maybe some other ones)? For example, the simplicity of use, the portability, the memory use, the speed, the readability of the error messages, the bugs(?), the comments about choices  in the implementation, etc.

If you want to know, I am working with Visual Studio but my code is (and should stay) compatible with Linux. The speed and memory usage are very important for me since I will compute and keep in memory a large amount of random Forests. The code that I am developing is a machine learning algorithm for symbolic time sequences.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I thinks this question is constructive  according to the upvoted result.